# Where did setting the background color in Pages go?

Tags: pages

With the last update (Nov 2021) to `Pages 11.2` the ability to set the background color of highlighted text seems to have vanished.

Now the only options are `(Advanced) Gradient Fill` and `(Advanced) Image Fill`? Is background color now just considered a special case of either? (and do these variations continue to be accepted by ms-word?)

Comment: I think it would be better if you put your edit as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

I see it now. It's been relegated to `Advanced Options`. Weird. This means that if I'm editing some writing and want to make sure my comments are clearly visible, by changing their background, I need to click three times to do it (after marking the text).

**Verdict**

Atrocious usability in `v11.2`. Avoid it if you can (at least if you need to change the text and background colors of various segments of text).

Comment: If you go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts and add Pages, you can then assign a keyboard shortcut to that option in Pages.